# How to get current database and user name with `SELECT` in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.2`.

Is there any way to get an output like,

> Database : mydb, User : myUser

using a **`SELECT`** query?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By using the inbuilt [System Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curren/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO)

1.) Currently using database

```
   select current_database()
```

2.) Connected User

```
  select user
```

To get the desired output use either this

```
 select 'Database : ' ||current_database()||', '||'User : '|| user db_details
```

or

```
select format('Database: %s, User: %s',current_database(),user) db_details
```

[`Live Demo`](http://rextester.com/HLKM90597)

Answer (score 25):

Check [this part of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html) for more functions.

```
SELECT current_user,
       user,
       session_user,
       current_database(),
       current_catalog,
       version();
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows the current database:

```sql
SELECT current_database();
```

This shows the current user:

```sql
SELECT current_user;
```