# How to check connected user on psql

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have 2 users: postgres and myuser.

The default user is postgres, but this user has no permission to query my foreign tables and myuser does. How can I check if I'm connected with the right user?

If I'm using the wrong user, how do I change to the right one?

Comment: This question may be interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277356/how-to-get-current-database-and-user-name-using-a-select-in-postgresql

Comment: `set role to username;` to change the current user without relogin.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

To get information about current connection from the psql command prompt:

```
\conninfo
```

This displays more informations, though.

To change user:

```
\c - a_new_user
```

‘-’ substitutes for the current database.

To change database **and** user:

```
\c a_new_database a_new_user
```

The SQL command to get this information:

```
SELECT current_user;
```

---

**Examples:**

```
postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432"

postgres=# \c a_new_database a_new_user
psql (12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg16.04+1), server 9.5.20)
You are now connected to database "a_new_database" as user "a_new_user".

a_new_database=# SELECT current_user;
 current_user 
--------------
 a_new_user
(1 row)
```

---

This page list few interesting functions and variables.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Comment: If you have changed users (roles) by using the `SET ROLE new_role` command `\conninfo` will still show the role that you connected as, not the role you currently are.

Comment: You’re right, @GregoryArenius. It’s probably best to do `SELECT current_user, session_user;` to figure out your current authorisation profile.

Comment: `\conninfo` will return something like `You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".`

It could be useful to others if you add the responses to your answer!

Comment: @JosephMCasey I have added examples.

Comment: Thanks but, How can I create new user without any password

Comment: @AnupamHaldkar I cannot help You on this. I am not experienced enough. You should find or create a question. It may be on StackOverflow, DatabaseAdministrators, ServerFault or something else.

Comment: fine @Michas I will look into it

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of the '-' for current database. Very helpful.

Answer (score 27):

To view your current authorisation:

```
SELECT session_user, current_user;
```

To change to another role to which you’ve been granted access:

```
SET ROLE <role_name>;
```

For instance, if you’ve granted the `postgres` role to `myuser` with…

```
GRANT postgres TO myuser;
```

… then `myuser` can temporarily “su” to `postgres` with:

```
SET ROLE postgres;
```

*Note (1):* Superusers can `SET ROLE` to any other role without explicitly being granted access to it.

*Note (2):* Using `SET ROLE` changes only `current_user` and not `session_user`.

To return to your default (session) role:

```
RESET ROLE;
```

If you’re logged in as a superuser, you can change the authorisation profile for the entire session with:

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION <role_name>;
```

This changes both `current_user` and `session_user`.

Postgres authorisation is a complicated (arguably over-complicated) topic. I suggest reading through the official documentation.

*Edit:* To make things simpler, I define the following alias in my `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\set whoami 'SELECT session_user, current_user, :''HOST'' host, :''PORT'' port, :''DBNAME'' dbname;’
```

Now I can simply type `:whoami` at the psql prompt to see my authorisation details.

Answer (score 5):

You can always run the query "select current_user" to determine who you are now.  As far as being the correct user, what database client are you using?  You would normally specify that information when you connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

in PostgreSql and by default the user is:

> postgres

if you want to find user name:

> pgAdmin => object => create script => "select session_user, current_user; "