# How to get the permission to create a role in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions, roles, privileges

When I try to create a new user or role I am getting

[42501] ERROR: permission denied to create role

I am executing

```
CREATE user test with PASSWORD 'xyz1234reee'
```

I am logged in as a superuser

Comment: have you granted the correct permissions to the current user? `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO your_user;` ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-grant.html ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277356/how-to-get-current-database-and-user-name-with-select-in-postgresql

Comment: Not reproducible.  Superusers can create users.  Maybe you aren't really a superuser.  Maybe you aren't really connected to PostgreSQL, but rather some hacked up fork.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not* logged in as a superuser.

Perhaps you are on a hosted database, and they gave you a user like `rds_superuser`. That sounds like a superuser, but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login as superuser postgees or else any other user who has privilege to create role.

Once you login as superuser, either you can create desired role or else you can grant createrole permission to a user in postgres.

If anyuser don't have permission to create role, it will throw error: permission denied to create role.

To assign permission to create role:

```
ALTER USER user_name CREATEROLE;
```

Now, you can login using above user and create role.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create the user(role) `john` with `CREATEROLE` privilege or add `CREATEROLE` privilege to the user(role) `john` as shown below. *You probably need to log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`) and you can omit `WITH` which is optional:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'apple' CREATEROLE;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH CREATEROLE;
```

Then, you can create, alter and drop the user(role) `david` by logging in with `john` as shown below. *Be careful, there is the restriction to add some privileges and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql#answer-77263012) explains how to create a database:

```sql
CREATE ROLE david WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'orange';
```

```sql
ALTER ROLE david WITH PASSWORD 'kiwi';
```

```sql
DROP ROLE david;
```